# why my angular code doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hey i am new with angular and i cant get it working
i made a new project where i put the angular.min.js file to and this code doesnt work and i dont know why it shows nothing
please help me understand why.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('list', []);

app.controller('peopleListCtrl', function(){
  this.persons = plists;
});

var plists = [
             { name: 'alon', job: 'web dev', home:'nir tzvi' },
{ name: 'ben', job: 'katbamflighter', home:'nir tzvi' },
{ name: 'shiraz', job: 'dentist assistant', home:'hadera west' }
];
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="list">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="peopleListCtrl as ppl">
<br />
<div ng-repeat="people in ppl.persons">
<h3>
 {{people.name}}
{{people.job}}
{{people.home}}
</h3>
  </div>
    <input type="text" />
<br />
</body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answers above, if you really want to use the `controller as` syntax in order to use methods and variables belonging to the controller object as opposed as the classical `$scope` injection, you need to use a more modern version of AngularJS I am afraid.

Here's your code using AngularJS v1.4.7: http://plnkr.co/edit/FIrK0o8493k3VjDBSNtM?p=preview

Hope it adds some clarification!

Answer (score 3):

Refer this for clarifications  [$scope vs this in AngularJS controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

see working code.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('list', []);

app.controller('peopleListCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.persons = plists;
}]);

var plists = [
             { name: 'alon', job: 'web dev', home:'nir tzvi' },
{ name: 'ben', job: 'katbamflighter', home:'nir tzvi' },
{ name: 'shiraz', job: 'dentist assistant', home:'hadera west' }
];
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="list">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="peopleListCtrl">
<br />
<div ng-repeat="people in persons">
<h3>
 {{people.name}}
{{people.job}}
{{people.home}}
</h3>
  </div>
    <input type="text" />
<br />
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your edition. Yes, I think `$scope` vs. `this` is the key to understand the issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this.persons with $scope.persons in the controller, the $scope will make sure you can use the data in your template.

```
app.controller('peopleListCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.persons = plists;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-controller should just be `peopleListCtrl` not `peopleListCtrl as ppl` in your HTML.

You will also need to change `this.persons` to `$scope.persons` in your controller.

Then change your HTML to this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="list">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="peopleListCtrl as ppl">
<br />
<div ng-repeat="people in persons">
<h3>
 {{people.name}}
{{people.job}}
{{people.home}}
</h3>
  </div>
   <input type="text" />
```